# Builder Pattern using Inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, builder

I have `CommonRequestBuilder` and `SpecificRequestBuilder`, that look like this.

```
public class CommonRequestBuilder 
{
    protected readonly BigRequest _request;

    public CommonRequestBuilder()
    {
         _request = new BigRequest();
    }

    public CommonRequestBuilder WithExtras()
    {
        // add extra stuff to _request
        return this;
    }

    public BigRequest Build()
    {
        return _request;
    }
}

public class SpecificRequestBuilder : CommonRequestBuilder
{
    public SpecificRequestBuilder WithDetails()
    {
        // add some stuff to _request
        return this;
    }

    public BigRequest Build()
    {
        return _request;
    }
}
```

The issue with this pattern, is that if I use SpecificRequestBuilder like this:

```
_specificRequestBuilder.WithExtras().WithDetails(); // WithDetails() is not found
```

In above code `WithDetails()` cannot be resolved because I am getting the base class from `WithExtras()`. I can re-arrange the methods to make it work, but is there a way I can update the classes so that any order works?

Comment: cast to the specific type? `((SpecificRequestBuilder )_specificRequestBuilder.WithExtras()).WithDetails()`

Comment: public static T WithDetails<T>(this T t) where T : CommonRequestBuilder
{
    // add some stuff to _request
    return t;
}

Comment: I saw this comment in your code: // add extra stuff to _request  Maybe, you should consider using the Decorator pattern instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use the `new` keyword in your `SpecificRequestBuilder` to have a method with a different return type:

```
public class SpecificRequestBuilder : CommonRequestBuilder
{
    public SpecificRequestBuilder WithDetails()
    {
        // add some stuff to _request
        return this;
    }


    public new SpecificRequestBuilder WithExtras()
    {
        return (SpecificRequestBuilder)base.WithExtras();
    }
}
```

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/tU4hEM

Comment: Yes, as a simple forwarding method, this is one situation where method hiding is appropriate. `WithExtras` should not be extended in this way though, or else the behaviour will differ depending on the reference type.

Comment: I think this is my only option. Not perfect, but it will do.

Answer (score 2):

In C# 9.0 (which is latest release, so please make sure you have it, it is shipped with VS 16.8.2) you can use [covariant overrides](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/covariant-returns), which would perfectly fit here. This would allow you to make such changes:

Just make method  `WithExtras` virtual and override it in base class with return type of `SpecificRequestBuilder`, like below

```
public class CommonRequestBuilder
{
    protected readonly BigRequest _request;

    public CommonRequestBuilder()
    {
        _request = new BigRequest();
    }

    public virtual CommonRequestBuilder WithExtras()
    {
        // add extra stuff to _request
        return this;
    }

    public BigRequest Build()
    {
        return _request;
    }
}

public class SpecificRequestBuilder : CommonRequestBuilder
{
    public override SpecificRequestBuilder WithExtras()
    {
        base.WithExtras();
        return this;
    }
    public SpecificRequestBuilder WithDetails()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public BigRequest Build()
    {
        return _request;
    }
}
```

Now statement

```
_specificRequestBuilder.WithExtras().WithDetails();
```

becomes completely valid.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would implement a true polymorphic approach.

A request builder should be interfaced, then it doesn't matter what the specific type of builder is:

```
interface IRequestBuilder
{
    IRequestBuilder WithExtras();
    IRequestBuilder WithDetails();
    BigRequest Build();
}
```

You can still provide a default implementation:

```
public class CommonRequestBuilder : IRequestBuilder
{
    protected readonly BigRequest _request;

    public CommonRequestBuilder()
    {
         _request = new BigRequest();
    }

    public virtual IRequestBuilder WithExtras()
    {
        // add extra stuff to _request
        return this;
    }
    
    // Default implementation
    IRequestBuilder IRequestBuilder.WithDetails() => this;

    public virtual BigRequest Build()
    {
        return _request;
    }
}
```

And make it more specific:

```
public class SpecificRequestBuilder : CommonRequestBuilder
{
    public IRequestBuilder WithDetails()
    {
        // add some stuff to _request
        return this;
    }
}
```

Now you can use any implementation you like:

```
IRequestBuilder builder = new SpecificRequestBuilder().WithExtras().WithDetails();
```

The default implementation of `WithDetails()` in `CommonRequestBuilder` has the added benefit of not allowing that method to be called when you are dealing with a `CommonRequestBuilder` variable, as it does nothing.

Comment: I like it. But, because we are trying to stay true to open/closed principle, I can't use this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare WithDetails on the base as a virtual method that can be overwritten.

```
public virtual CommonRequestBuilder WithDetails()
```

Build also has to be virtual on the base to be overwritten

```
public BigRequest Build()
```

You'll have the problem that WithDetails on the derived class cannot returnSpecialRequestBuilder.

I would create an interface that can be implemented by various implementations. Unless sticking to working with CommonRequestBuilder (or BaseRequestBuilder) works well enough.

```
public interface IRequestBuilder
{
    IRequestBuilder WithExtras();
    IRequestBuilder WithDetails();
    BigRequest Build();
}

public class CommonRequestBuilder : IRequestBuilder
{
    // ...
}

public class SpecificRequestBuilder : CommonRequestBuilder, IRequestBuilder
{
    // ...
}
```